# Win2008 R2 IIS 7.5 "No Default Printer Installed" error from Isapi Web Service

Tags: delphi, iis, printing, windows-server-2008-r2, isapi

I have a delphi dll that is generating a error "no default printer installed" when i try to generate a report to pdf. I have create a local account and had the service impersonate the user. I have given rights to the site directory to this user. I do have a default printer installed and have given print and print management rights to the user account - along with IIS_IUSR.

This setup has worked in the past on the same configuration, but doesn't seem to be working a new machine with the same setup.

I've even made the user have admin rights but still the same error. No sure what is wrong with this setup but i know it works as i have other servers with the same setup.

any help is appreciated. The machine profile follows - thanks:

Delphi 7
Windows 2008 Server R2
IIS 7.5.6

Comment: What type of printer is it? Is it a network printer or a locally connected printer?

Comment: It is just the printer driver... the driver is a local printer.

Comment: I missed the PDF part. I had problems in the past (it was a while back) with a certain PDF driver (I can't remember the name but it was on SourceForge) and ended up putting the printer name in a config file and using that. It seems like you are doing everything right. This sounds like an environmental issue and not a Delphi specific on. This link may help you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2013/06/24/printing-from-a-windows-service.aspx

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. The article is very good - will bookmark it for future review. Yea - the issue is the environment. Just cannot figure out what is different from one server to another. Basically, i am generating a PDF using QuickReports and eDocEngine.  As i mentioned it works perfect on all IIS below 7.5. But on this one win 2008 server machine it just fails. I even tried using the admin account for the application pool and it still doesn't see the printer. Everything i found on the web points to impersonating a user account but that doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Ok - figured it out. The difference (hate when i make bone-headed mistakes) was that the authentication was left on IUSR for the problem machine - should have been set to the application pool. All the other machines were set to the application pool. Thanks again for talking me through it.